# iCloud iCon in Settings showing white only in iOS

Tags: ios, icons, settings, icloud

In my app , I am using `iCloud` features.

However when i go to `settings` > `iCloud` > `Manage Storage` , my app icon is only show white.

I have already added iCon-Small and all @2x into my project and also I tried delete my app from my iPad and run again. That's showing only white iCon like the following pic.

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: change the name "icon-small" to icon.png

Answer (score 3):

If your app is not live then you cant seen application icon in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in a long-standing live app (so not in initial development) - the same white generic icon as you're seeing, and also the bundle name is used, rather than the bundle display name which is subtly different in my case. It's not just you and me, Pixelmator also appears the same on my devices - and it's bundle name also looks to be slightly off from the display name as well.

I suspect however this is a cached server side thing in iCloud. I have many apps listed that I've never installed on certain devices, including OS X apps on my iOS devices - so this is something that is probably uploaded to iCloud when your app update is processed by Apple.

This problem started for me sometime after I implemented Asset Catalogs for storing my app icons, and looking in my Info.plist, I can see I still have some of the old icon keys referenced, though the icon file references themselves have been removed from the plist. I'm wondering if this slight misconfiguration led to iTunes Connect incorrectly processing my binary and failing to extract the image from the asset catalog. However, I don't see how this would lead to the wrong bundle name being applied, unless this is just what the iCloud settings screen does.

I'll update this if the next update fixes it. It could even just be a sporadic error or bug on Apple's end.

Comment: Hello @rob-glassey, any update on this? I have been facing the same problem and I didn't figure it out what can I do to fix it.

Comment: @tiago-pereira - nope. It was a low priority problem for me, so hasn't been tackled. I keep meaning to get in touch with Apple Support directly about this, but there's always something else needing dealt with. I'd suggest trying that if you need a rapid solution. In my case it's only the iCloud Settings Manage Storage screen that's broken, and it's the sort of thing that's used once in a blue moon. Looking on my iPhone just now, I can see 3 other apps with this problem. To me it feels like a server side issue, or something that app upload verification should check for but doesn't.